# Python: building unique connections graph

Tags: python, graph

So there's a problem: given two dicts - lists of network hosts, I have to build a graph of possible connections between them (and limited to using Python + external modules here), limited by some rules.

```
clients = { 
        "mach1": ["a1cli1", "a1cli2", "a1cli3", "a1cli4"],
        "mach2": ["a2cli1", "a2cli2", "a2cli3", "a2cli4"],
        "mach3": ["a3cli1", "a3cli2", "a3cli3", "a3cli4"],
        "mach4": ["a4cli1", "a4cli2", "a4cli3", "a4cli4"],
        "mach5": ["a5cli1", "a5cli2", "a5cli3", "a5cli4"]
    }

servers = {
        "mach1": ["1serv1", "1serv2"],
        "mach2": ["2serv1", "2serv2"],
        "mach3": ["3serv1", "3serv2"],
        "mach4": ["4serv1", "4serv2"],
        "mach5": ["5serv1", "5serv2"]
}
```

Each client can form connections to multiple servers (to N servers / N clients), each server can take only 1 incoming connection, connections between client/servers on same hosts are not allowed, and output should look like something more or less fairly distributed (so there should be no situations when all of machine X endpoints are connected with machine Y inputs).

Current python solution is ~70 lines and has annoying problem with one of nodes not getting enough tests (so quickfixed to work on current test data set), https://repl.it/BFWD/1

What existing module can be used to deal with this type of graph problems? I have to implement this in python.. found about NetworkX but not sure if it will fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Practical Graph/Network Analysis Made Simple" - using NetworkX - was a fantastic presentation at PyCon 2015:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_k4MOh7J7YY

And here you can find 7 ipython notebooks with almost self-explaining examples:

- https://github.com/ericmjl/Network-Analysis-Made-Simple

Definitely the best introduction I found.

The first 30 minutes here are also quite interesting:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Lauxn9oTt4
- https://github.com/sarguido/networkx-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

NetworkX is a really good solution, it allows you to work with network graphs more easily as well as drawing them. But to draw the graph you will need to install matplotlib too. Take a look at the [NetworkX Drawing Documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/drawing.html) and at their [Drawing Tutorial](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/tutorial/tutorial.html#drawing-graphs)